# How can we resolve 'certificate verify failed' error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run this simple script on my company laptop.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="ryan_data")
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
print(location.address)
```

When I run that code I get this error message.

```
GeocoderUnavailable: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?q=175+5th+Avenue+NYC&format=json&limit=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

If I run the exact code on my personal laptop, everything works totally fine. I think there is some kind of VPN issue or maybe firewall issue, on the corporate laptop. I Googled the error and found a couple things on this topic, but not much really. I feel like there should be an easy work-around, but after Googling this and trying a couple ideas, I am still stuck! Has anyone here encountered this issue and resolved it? If so, please do share your thoughts!

Comment: The error is, "certificate verify failed", which in most cases has nothing to do with your VPN or firewall (although it's possible a bad corporate proxy could result in this error). In most cases, it means your system doesn't have the appropriate CA certificate installed in order to trust the remote certificate. You need to install the appropriate certificate where Python can find it. How to do this varies by operating system, distribution, and exactly how you installed Python.?

Comment: In order to further understand the problem: What operating system/distribution are you using? Do you get the same error if you try connecting to `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org` using `curl`? Are there any proxies configured in your environment (e.g. via the `https_proxy` environment variable)?